# mix A with B, replace A with B

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

In "mix A with B" and "replace A with B," do A and B **both** have to be nouns or noun phrases?

**EDIT**: Can one of the nouns in those phrases be **dropped**?

Are the following okay?

> a. The artist mixes Eastern style with **Western** in her work. (Here, "Western" is an adjective)

> b. The artist mixes **Eastern** with Western styles in her work. (Here, "Eastern" is an adjective)

> c. The ducts draw out exhaust air and replace it with **fresh**. (Here, "fresh" is an adjective)

Comment: I know that you've been on this site for a while and know about doing research before asking questions. In your question, "A" is a direct object and "B" is an object of a preposition. Therefore, you seem to be asking whether those objects must be nouns or noun phrases. Is that right? Does that help you to research the issue?

Comment: My question can (or perhaps should) be rephrased as: Can one of the nouns in those phrases be dropped?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that I wasn't clear. I meant that this issue has nothng to do with "mix", "replace", etc. For example: "The Eastern style, not the Western, influences her work." This is a broader issue. I thought that perhaps you weren't sure about how to research it and was trying to help.